# Default username for ec2 instance spawned by elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to use elastic beanstalk to deploy an application and one of the things I need to do is be able to log into the underlying ec2 instance and add dependencies.  I added a key pair to the instance and put the private key file in ~/.ssh on my computer.  Next I specified the key pair for the ec2 instance and it restarted and eventually the status was green

When I try to ssh into the ec2 instance I get the following error:

```
$ ssh ec2-user@myinstance.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
ec2-user@myinstance.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

In the docs is says this could be due to an incorrect username.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html

Does anyone know what the default username is for ec2 instances created by elastic beanstalk?

Also if I'm doing this all wrong would appreciate some pointers there too.

Comment: If you are using the [eb cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html), then you can also ssh in by running the command: `$ eb ssh my-environment-name`. This way you don't need to worry if the underlying instance has changed and have to look up the new public DNS each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.To make sure that the there's no mistake the way you connect:

- Go to EC2-> Instances
- Select your instance
- And press Connect

You should get the command to connect from the instructions from the Connect Popup. The correct username is mentioned there plus instructiins on how to set the correct permissions on the pem (applies to linux)

2.
Make sure that you modified the security group of the instance you're trying to connect do that it allows ssh from the ip of your pc. (This is not the case for the question, since the error is Permission denied (publickey), it means that it's not an sg issue, thx @diego)

3.
Also if you connect from a corporate network, try connecting from another network. It might be firewall issue.

4.
Last but not least make sure you ssh inside the .ssh path, or provide the correct pem path

Comment: If I look at it in EB, it looks like the key pair is set up.  However the EC2 instance says that the Instance is not associated with a key pair when I try to connect instructions.

Comment: If you scroll to the right of the ec2 console don't you see the associated key pair? Is the right instance the one you are trying to connect?

Comment: You know what, my ec2 dashboard wasn't updating and I was pointing to the instance that was killed when I updated with the key pair.  Tried it with the newer instance and it worked.

Comment: if it explicitly says `Permission denied (publickey)` then we know it's not a security group problem